# Customize HTML img tags with Java Regular Expressions

Tags: java, html, regex

I'm new to regular expressions, but I believe this is the method for my solution.  I'm trying to take an arbitrary HTML snippet and customize the image tags.  For example,

If I had this HTML code:
`<><><><><img src="blah.jpg"><><><><><><><><img src="blah2.jpg"><><><>`

I want to turn it into:
`<><><><><img src="images/blah.jpg"><><><><><><><><img src="images/blah2.jpg"><><><>`

The Code I have now is this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<img.*src=\".*\\..*\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher(htmlString);
boolean b = m.find();

String imgPath = "src=\"images/";

while(b)
{
    //Get file name.
    String name="test.jpg\"";

    //Assign new path.
    m.group().replaceAll("src=\".*\"",imgPath+name);
}
```

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing.  I don't know what the regular expression should look like or how to replace the original HTML with my modified version.

Comment: the problem is that you shouldn't use regex to parse HTML. For instance, `.*` searches only for characters on the same line, so a return between the `img` and the `src` breaks the search. Secondly, `img.*src` is not right: this searches for `img` and any number of characters and the _last_ occurrence of `src` on the same line. You don't want that; it would catch both images in your example in the same result. And HTML attributes can have single quotes instead of double ones. And whitespace around the `=` sign is allowed by HTML, but not by your regex. And so on, and so forth.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but at the same time I have no idea how to proceed with another method for breaking down the HTML tags.  I do however, have some kind of functional code now, but with some problems.  The img tags are being customized, but the problem I have now is that it's always setting every img tag to the same customization.

For example, 

<><><img src="blah.jpg">

Turns into <><><img src="images/blah.jpg"> for all the img tags.

Comment: I can't see what exactly you're trying to do from the Java source you posted here. (This is an infinite loop because `b` never changes.) I'm pretty sure the base problem is as I mentioned though: the regex returns `<img src="blah"><><><><img src="blah2"` instead of just `<img src="blah"`

Comment: Since I am close to a solution, I would consider using maybe a switch statement to address some variants as you mentioned (or I could try learning more about regex to possibly come up with something better).  In the simplest terms, I am trying to take the source attribute and insert a foldername before the filename.  Additionally, if I can get all the matches on the img tag then I can  get all the filenames as desired and my code would be almost done.

Comment: Traditional answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is almost perfect.  It prints out alot of info, so look for where it says "Final result"  and "original" to see the result of customizing the IMG tags.  There's a small flaw that I'm still not sure how to fix.  "in10" is the variable for testing an input string.  The rest are regex.

I noticed problems occur when I use newline characters and when "src=" is left blank instead of "src=\"\"" or "src=''" The quotes seem to effect the results.

```
private static String r16 = "(?s)(<img.*?)(src\\s*?=\\s*?(?:\"|').*?(?:\"|'))";
private static String in10 = "<><><><><img width=1 height=888 src=\"bnm.jpg\"<><><><><img src=\"\"> <img src = \"\"><img src ='folder1/folder2/bnm.jpg'><><><img src =\"'>";
private static String r14 = "(?s)\\/|\\=";




    String path="images/";
    String name="";

   Pattern p = Pattern.compile(r16);

   Matcher m = p.matcher(in10); 


   StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
   int i=1;
   while(m.find())
   {
        String g0 = m.group();
        String g2 = m.group(2);
        System.out.println("Main group"+i+":"+g0);
        System.out.println("Inner group1:"+m.group(1));
        System.out.println("Inner group2:"+g2);




            String[] names=g2.split(r14);
            printNames(names);

            /*
             * src="/folder1/folder2/blah.jpg"  --->  blah.jpg
             * src="bnm.jpg"                    --->  src="bnm.jp"
             */

            if(names.length>=1)
            {
                name = names[names.length-1];
            }
            else
            {
                name = "";
            }
        //Name might be empty string.
        name = name.replaceAll("\"|'","");
        System.out.println("Retrieved Name:"+name);
        m.appendReplacement(sb,"$1src=\""+path+name+"\"");
        i++;
   }
   m.appendTail(sb);
    INPUT=sb.toString();
   System.out.println("Final Result:"+INPUT);
   System.out.println("Original____:"+in10);
   System.out.println("Count:"+m.groupCount());        
}
```

Comment: I made some minor tweaks to the regex above.  I now believe the code to work, but need to perform some more testing.  In particular, r17 includes "(?s)" and r14 = "(?s)\\/|(\\s*+\\=\\s*+)"  Also to note, but an extremely minor detail is when src='' is replaced, regardless of quotes used, I always replace with double quotes, and not leave the previous quotes intact.

Comment: Update:  r17 completely removed, it's no longer needed.  Some testing revealed the regex for r16 needs changing since it shouldn't match against src= or src=\" or src='  in other words, there must be double quotes of some kind used.  Also, I don't know how to denote newline in Windows O/S, so for a test string I used:  System.getProperty("line.separator") in a string to represent newlines; the code seems to work as intended when newlines are used.

Comment: I realized r16 only had a problem with src='src=' in other words, if the src= was nested. I don't know how to get this negated and removed from matching. Previously I was displaying the wrong original string and thought my pattern was matching src= when in fact it wasn't. I'll update the code.

Answer (score 8):

[Regular expressions are not the correct way to parse HTML.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/201952)  Don't do it.  It's not possible to do correctly.

[Use a proper parser.](http://jsoup.org/)

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(someHtml);
Elements imgs = doc.select("img");
for (Element img : imgs) {
    img.attr("src", "images/" + img.attr("src")); // or whatever
}

doc.outerHtml(); // returns the modified HTML
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use regex for this.The way which josh3736 said is robust.But if you want to use regex you should use :

```
String s = "<><><><><img src=\"blah.jpg\"><><><><><><><><img src=\"blah2.jpg\"><><><>";
s = s.replaceAll("(?<=img src=\")([^\"]+)(?=\">)","images/$1");
System.out.println(s);
```

output :

```
<><><><><img src="images/blah.jpg"><><><><><><><><img src="images/blah2.jpg"><><><>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with the others that doing this with regular expressions is the wrong way to modify html fragments, here is a JUnit test case that shows how to replace src elements with a Pattern in Java:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ImgSrcReplace {

  @Test
  public void replaceWithRegex() {
    String dir = "image/";
    String htmlFragment = "<body>\n"+
    "<img src=\"single-line.jpg\">"+
    "<img src=\n"+
    "\"multiline.jpg\">\n"+
    "<img src='single-quote.jpg'><img src=\"broken.gif\'>"+
    "<img class=\"before\" src=\"class-before.jpg\">"+
    "<img src=\"class-after.gif\" class=\"after\">"+
    "</body>";


    Pattern replaceImgSrc =
      Pattern.compile(
        "(<img\\b[^>]*\\bsrc\\s*=\\s*)([\"\'])((?:(?!\\2)[^>])*)\\2(\\s*[^>]*>)",
        Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE&Pattern.MULTILINE);

    String result = 
      replaceImgSrc.matcher(htmlFragment)
        .replaceAll("$1$2"+Matcher.quoteReplacement(dir)+"$3$2$4");

    assertThat("the single line image tag was updated", result, 
      containsString("image/single-line.jpg"));
    assertThat("the multiline image tag was updated", result, 
      containsString("image/multiline.jpg"));
    assertThat("the single quote image tag was updated", result, 
      containsString("image/single-quote.jpg"));
    assertThat("the broken gif was ignored.", result, 
      containsString("\"broken.gif'"));
    assertThat("attributes before are preseved.", result, 
      containsString("<img class=\"before\" src=\"image/class-before.jpg\">"));
    assertThat("attributes after are preseved.", result, 
      containsString("<img src=\"image/class-after.gif\" class=\"after\">"));
  }

}
```